# Giving access to intranet without handling internet access [Windows server 2012 r2]

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012-r2, internal-dns, site-to-site-vpn, intranet

I have an hard time explaining what I am looking for, but essentially, I am trying to open up my intranet to secure clients like a VPN would, but without handling their normal internet activity.

Is this a thing? I have a few VM on a server for various development projects (I am a rookie) and I would like to share access to them to friends via secure connection, but without having them go through my server for all their internet needs like it is currently set up with RRAS VPN.

It might not be possible because I guess that could create conflicts by joining intranets (i.e 2 192.0.x.x identical address). But I thought it was worth to ask.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [remote desktop services](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831447%28v=ws.11%29.aspx) in windows server 2012 r2.  You can build gateway and web boxes to secure your configuration properly, publish apps that they need to be able to use, and not worry about proxying all of their internet

Comment: If one of my VM has GIT on it, will setting it up with with something like git.example.com work for them when connected to my remote desktop services?
I also had an issue where I am not able to install remote desktop services and I think it's due to the fact that I also have AD/Domain controller onto that box?

Comment: Yeah that wouldn't work for either of those examples, unfortunately.